# Redirect to a Page on 404 Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

Is it possible to redirect to a page on 404 and 500 instead of constructing a custom response? I tried-

```
class NotFoundPageHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):        
        #if 400
        self.redirect('error/notfound.html')
        #if 500 how to check

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                       [
                                         ('/', MainPage),
                                         ('/index.html', MainPage),
                                         ('.*', NotFoundPageHandler)
                                       ], debug=True)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please, please don't do this. When there's an error, serve the appropriate error code, don't redirect users to an 'error' page. It breaks the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to redirect. What you want is a custom error page.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Custom_Error_Responses

```
error_handlers:
  - file: default_error.html

  - error_code: over_quota
    file: over_quota.html
```

`- error_code: 404` or `- error_code: 500` should work too. Read that link carefully, it sounds like you have to be careful those files aren't in a static file directory.

Comment: I already went through it and added to my yaml file. But this doesn't work even though the file path is correct.

Comment: Did you get rid of the `('.*', NotFoundPageHandler)`? Did you make sure you're not overlapping a static file dir? IF that doesn't work, I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Yes I did get rid of it. I moved that not found file from root to a new folder which is not inside static dir. Still no luck. :(